# Find last record of similar group in html table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with similar group like this

```
Class        StudentName          RollNo.
Class A      John                 1
Class A      Mathew               2
Class A      Kevin                3
Class B      Donald               1
Class B      Miller               2
```

I want to fetch last record of Class A and Class B such as

```
Class A          Kevin        3
```

and

```
Class B          Miller       2
```

Here is my HTML Table Structure

```
<table class="style1">
    <tr>
        <td class="style2">
            Class</td>
        <td class="style3">
            StudentName</td>
        <td class="style4">
            RollNo</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Can you provide the `html` structure?

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you can iterate throw all rows and save last one in each class.

```js
var lastInClass = {};

$('table tr').each(function() {
  var row = $(this);
  var rowClass = row.find('td:first').text().trim();
  
  lastInClass[rowClass] = row;
});

$.each(lastInClass, function(rowClass, row) {
  $('<div>').text('Last in class ' + rowClass + ' is ' + row.text()).appendTo('#result');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="style1">
  <tr>
        <td class="style2">
          Class A
        </td>
        <td class="style3">
          John
        </td>
        <td class="style4">
          1
        </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td class="style2">
          Class A
        </td>
        <td class="style3">
          Mathew
        </td>
        <td class="style4">
          2
        </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
        <td class="style2">
          Class A
        </td>
        <td class="style3">
          Kevin
        </td>
        <td class="style4">
          3
        </td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
        <td class="style2">
          Class B
        </td>
        <td class="style3">
          Donald
        </td>
        <td class="style4">
          1
        </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td class="style2">
          Class B
        </td>
        <td class="style3">
          Miller
        </td>
        <td class="style4">
          2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="result"></div>
```

But I believe better approach is to mark those rows server side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the rows, extracting the cell values and comparing with the previous or next sibling. The last one should get included in the result always. There are many ways to iterate over the rows, one of them below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var res = extractGroupTails();
  res.forEach(function(item, index){
    $("#result").append(index + " ");
    $("#result").append(item.join(',') + "<br/>");
  });
});

function extractGroupTails(){
  var result = [];
  $("#myTable tr").each(function(index){
    var currentRow = getArray($(this)),
        nextRow = getArray($(this).next());

    if(currentRow.length === 0){
        // table header
    }else if(nextRow.length === 0 || currentRow[0] !== nextRow[0]){
          result.push(currentRow);
    }
  });
  return result;
}

function getArray($row){
    var res = [];
  $($row).children("td").each(function(index){
    res.push($(this).html());
  });
  return res;
}
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrf141k0/2/)